# DM command to open last dataset in rwork library

Tags: sas, sas-macro

dm "vt &syslast";

The above command opens the last created dataset in work library.
How do I make it work for RWORK library?

Comment: sorry ..I menat this for BASE SAS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dm "vt &syslast."` will open the *most recently created table*, regardless of what location it is stored in.  So if the most recently created table is in `RWORK`, that should not be a problem.

What might be a problem is the definition of `&syslast`, however.  If you are doing something like:

```
rsubmit;
  data class;
    set sashelp.class;
  run;
endrsubmit;
dm "vt &syslast.";
```

That won't work - `&syslast` is defined on the remote computer, not on your local computer.  You either need to use [`%sysrput`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/connref/61908/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002590503.htm) to put the macro variable onto your local machine, or know the name of the dataset you want to open.

```
rsubmit;
  data class;
    set sashelp.class;
  run;
  %sysrput rdata=&syslast;
endrsubmit;
dm "vt &rdata";
```

Or something along those lines.  I think you'd probably have to translate the libname - `&rdata` would contain `WORK.CLASS` here, and you'd have to add an R - but it might be as simple as:

```
dm "vt R&rdata";
```

since you just want to prepend an R.

You could also directly specify the table, `dm "vt rwork.tablename"`, and open any arbitrary table.

`DM` commands only work in SAS Display Manager environment (often called "Base SAS") and will not work in Enterprise Guide or SAS Studio.  Both EG and Studio automatically open tables created during the current submission, by default, though the option to do so can be turned off.

Comment: This does not work for rwork library. A window pops up with a message table_NULL_ does not exist ( because there are no datasets in work library) or cannot be displayed.

Comment: I'm guessing at what you're doing here, and it would've been helpful to have a more complete question to avoid that guessing - but if you're trying to retrieve the `&SYSLAST` value from the remote client, your problem is not the `dm` command but the `&SYSLAST` value.  I edited the answer to include information on that.

Comment: Joe thanks so much for the answer. appreciate it!. yes, I was trying to open the data set from a remote client. rsubmit;%sysrput rdata=&syslast; endrsubmit; dm "vt R&rdata";  works